# Realtime complex Geoquery within Firebase for 100K users

Tags: javascript, firebase, geolocation, real-time, geohashing

**The use case:**

- 50K to 100K trucks updating both location and internal engine info in real time.
- From a console, it's crucial to update the interface every time a truck within some range changes location OR changes internal engine info. So if location is the same but engine info is new, should trigger update.

**The problem:**

- Geofire only queries by location, so I'd have to create a Geoquery AND listen to each truck's info individually, which is impracticable ad expensive both in Realtime DB and Firestore.
- Firestore is not clear about real time listeners combined with Geoqueries(as far as I know there is no onSnapshot for Geoqueries in Firestore and even so would be super expensive for this case).

**The suboptimal alternative:**
[Web Javascript Firebase V9 Modular]
I would use Firestore, create a Geoquery for a given range(which is static, not real time) and get all docs from it. Then in the console the user would only see real time info by clicking into a specific truck(document), so I could attach onSnapshot to that document.

Is this use case simply not supported or is there a way to model data to accommodate it at a reasonable cost ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoFire is only fully supported on the Realtime Database. GeoFire's data is intended to be kept separate from your own data and linked to it by a unique key/id. This minimises the indexing required to execute queries and minimises the data handed around while querying.

There is a [workaround for Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries) but it's not ideal for your use case because it grabs all the nearby records then filters the rest on the client.

If you are curious, a GeoFire entry looks similar to the following when uploaded (this is formatted for readability):

```js
"path/to/geofire/": {
  "<key>/": {
    ".priority": string, // a geohash, hidden
    "g": string, // a geohash
    "l": {
      "0": number, // latitude, number
      "1": number, // longitude, number
    }
  }
}
```

As can be seen above, there isn't any user-provided data here only a "key". This key can have any meaning such as the code of an airport in a registry, a push ID under a Realtime Database location, a Cloud Firestore document ID or some base64-encoded data.

With the introduction of Firestore, a number of users store the GeoFire data in the Realtime Database and link it back to Cloud Firestore documents using the key stored in GeoFire.

In the below example, a `truckInfo` object looks like this:

```js
interface TruckInfo {
  key: string;
  location: Geopoint; // [number, number]
  distance: number;
  snapshot: DataSnapshot | undefined;
  cancelling?: number; // an ID from a setTimeout call
  errorCount: number; // number of errors trying to attach data listener
  hidden?: true; // indicates whether the vehicle is currently out of range
  listening?: boolean; // indicates whether the listener was attached successfully
}
```

For the below code to work, you must define two callback methods:

```js
const truckUpdatedCallback = (truckInfo, snapshot) => { // or you can use ({ key, location, snapshot }) => { ... }
  // TODO: handle new trucks, updated locations and/or updated truck info
  // truckInfo.hidden may be true!
}

const truckRemovedCallback = (truckInfo, snapshot) => {
  // TODO: remove completely (deleted/out-of-range)
}
```

These callbacks are then invoked by the following "engine":

```js
const firebaseRef = ref(getDatabase(), "gf"), // RTDB location for GeoFire data
  trucksColRef = collection(getFirestore(), "trucks"), // Firestore location for truck-related data
  geoFireInstance = new geofire.GeoFire(firebaseRef),
  trackedTrucks = new Map(), // holds all the tracked trucks
  listenToTruck = (truckInfo) => { // attaches the Firestore listeners for the trucks
    if (truckInfo.cancelling !== void 0) {
      clearTimeout(truckInfo.cancelling);
      delete truckInfo.cancelling;
    }
   
    if (truckInfo.listening || truckInfo.errorCount >= 3)
      return; // do nothing.

    truckInfo.unsub = onSnapshot(
      truckInfo.docRef,
      (snapshot) => {
        truckInfo.listening = true;
        truckInfo.errorCount = 0;
        truckInfo.snapshot = snapshot;
        truckUpdatedCallback(truckInfo, snapshot); // fire callback
      },
      (err) => {
        truckInfo.listening = false;
        truckInfo.errorCount++;
        console.error("Failed to track truck #" + truckInfo.key, err);
      }
    )
  },
  cancelQuery = () => { // removes the listeners for all trucks and disables query
    // prevents all future updates
    geoQuery.cancel();
    trackedTrucks.forEach(({unsub}) => {
      unsub && unsub();
    });
  };

const geoQuery = geoFireInstance.query({ center, radius });

geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
  let truckInfo = trackedTrucks.get(key);

  if (!truckInfo) {
    // new truck to track
    const docRef = document(trucksColRef, key);
    truckInfo = { key, location, distance, docRef, errorCount: 0 };
    trackedTrucks.set(key, truckInfo);
  } else {
    // truck has re-entered watch area, update position
    Object.assign(truckInfo, { location, distance });
    delete truckInfo.hidden;
  }

  listenToTruck(truckInfo);
});

geoQuery.on("key_moved", function(key, location, distance) {
  const truckInfo = trackedTrucks.get(key);
  if (!truckInfo) return; // not being tracked?
  Object.assign(truckInfo, { location, distance });
  truckUpdatedCallback(truckInfo, snapshot); // fire callback
});

geoQuery.on("key_exited", function(key, location, distance) {
  const truckInfo = trackedTrucks.get(key);
  if (!truckInfo) return; // not being tracked?

  truckInfo.hidden = true;

  const unsub = truckInfo.unsub,
    cleanup = () => { // removes any listeners for this truck and removes it from tracking
      unsub && unsub();
      truckInfo.listening = false;
      trackedTrucks.delete(key);
      truckRemovedCallback(truckInfo, snapshot); // fire removed callback
    };

  if (location === null && distance === null) {
    // removed from database, immediately remove from view
    return cleanup();
  }

  // keep getting updates for at least 60s after going out of
  // range in case vehicle returns. Afterwards, remove from view
  truckInfo.cancelling = setTimeout(cleanup, 60000);

  // fire callback (to hide the truck)
  truckUpdatedCallback(truckInfo, snapshot);
});
```

Comment: If you'd like me to clarify anything, let me know. The engine bit is probably a bit confusing.

Comment: Great answer (as usual) Sam!  Very interesting to store the truck data in Firestore while the geodata is in RTDB. It makes a lot of sense, yet somehow never occurred to me. --- fyi: the Android version of GeoFire supports having the object data and geodata in the same database branch. I'm not a fan of this myself, but Sam Stern liked the idea and it would save needing separate listeners for each object's data here.

Comment: Quite astute to use both databases like that and very complete answer, thanks Sam!
A couple questions to be sure I got it:
1. Considering within the same Geoquery there could be a couple hundreds of trucks, does Firestore manage all those onSnapshots in an effective manner ?
2. The cancelQuery in the beginning would be for totally cancelling both Firestore and RTDB events ?

I believe truckRemovedCallback has an arrow where should be an equal sign.

Comment: @AugustoM.G. RE #1: If you are showing a single location, the Firestore event manager should handle each registration just fine. To my knowledge, the Firestore server doesn't have an actual limit on the number of listeners, instead choosing to throttle the connection as an abuse prevention measure. RE #2: `cancelQuery` handles the Firestore listeners directly and lets the GeoFire query handle disconnecting any RTDB listeners it is managing. So yes, both event chains are handled. RE #3: Good spot on the extra character, that's what I get for using StackOverflow as my IDE.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I didn't know about the Android variant. Unfortunately if its only in the Android SDK it's not the most cross-platform compatible solution. Additionally I'd only ever use it for small, mostly static datasets with largely static data. Even if supported everywhere, I don't think its the right approach for the use case and scale Augusto is looking at. The idea to use both databases is a holdover from using the RTDB for value-value maps such as user ID to email - the RTDB is just that bit easier to follow and lean enough to scale nicely.

Comment: Normally I completely agree that most object data is static, while geodata is more dynamic. OP's problems seems unusual in that sense (from what he shared in an exchange on LinkedIn), so it might be a better match here. But yeah... it'd require modifying the GeoFire libs, which is somewhat of an acquired taste. :-D --- And your approach sounds great, so  (I had already upvoted it earlier).

Comment: @samthecodingman Do you know any reason why Geofire does not support adding specific data(like an object with many fields) together with the Geo data ? As far as I've been investigating Geofire and RTDB it could be done and would allow receiving all needed information from the same events used in Geofire.

Comment: @AugustoM.G. No idea. I'm also just a third party dev. You could fork the code to add the feature yourself if needed.